# Does anyone know the patent number for First Response™ Gold™ Digital Pregnancy Test by Church &Dwight?

Tags: patentability, patent-infringement

First Response was reformulated to include  a new antibody to hCG beta-core fragment in a digital pregnancy test. Does anyone know whether Church & Dwight have filed patents on this new test?

Comment: Hi, AskPatents is an online service in Q&A format where users help find **prior art** on specific **US Patent Applications** and ask questions about the US Patent process. Questions about technology implementation details are outside the scope of Ask Patents. Please see [faq] for more information about which topics are on topic for Ask Patents and feel free to resubmit. Sorry for any confusion.

Comment: You could type inassignee:"Church & Dwight Co., Inc." into google patents to start looking for this.